# Is there a single word to describe "just another random thought"?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

I'm looking for a single word to describe: just another random thought

Or a single word to describe : the state of being lost in random thoughts

Comment: Is maybe "absent-minded" what you're looking for?

Comment: "Wool-gathering" means thinking about nothing in particular.  "Occurencia" is "the thing that occurred to me," but that's Spanish, alas.

Comment: I think the word you're looking for is "stoned".

Answer (score 1):

I think you are describing a ['daydream'](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/daydream?s=t)

> **noun**
>   1- a reverie indulged in while awake.
>
> **verb** (used without object)
>
> 2- to indulge in such a reverie.
>
> *www.dictionary.com*

... with the state being 'daydreaming'...

Answer (score 0):

Being *sidetracked* comes to mind. or although more than one word *off the wall* also seems to fit.

Answer (score 0):

You are **free-associating**.

American Heritage definition of *free association*: "A spontaneous, logically unconstrained and undirected association of ideas, emotions, and feelings."